# SELECT FROM TABLE INNER JOIN TABLE ORDER BY RAND AND DESC

Tags: mysql

so the situation is like this , i'm using the below query to fetch details from database inner joining the table 2 with order by desc but i want hem to be also rand() but don't know how , i have also tried it with subquery but not working or maybe i have done it in wrong way:

```
SELECT *,count(rating.photo_id) cphoto_id FROM rating INNER JOIN photos    ON photos.id = rating.photo_id  WHERE display = 1 GROUP BY rating.photo_id ORDER BY cphoto_id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

an help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (SELECT *,count(rating.photo_id) cphoto_id FROM rating INNER JOIN  photos    ON photos.id = rating.photo_id  WHERE display = 1 GROUP BY rating.photo_id ORDER BY cphoto_id DESC LIMIT 0,10) as alais order by rand();
```

Comment: error : Duplicate column name 'user_id' because both tables contains column called: user_id

Comment: By inner query u mean in sql console?

Comment: does this one work? SELECT *,count(rating.photo_id) cphoto_id FROM rating INNER JOIN  photos    ON photos.id = rating.photo_id  WHERE display = 1 GROUP BY rating.photo_id ORDER BY cphoto_id DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: yes this normal query works , but when trying it with rand() does not works

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It might work.

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT photos.*,rating.*,count(rating.photo_id) cphoto_id 
  FROM rating INNER JOIN  photos ON photos.id = rating.photo_id  
  WHERE display = 1 GROUP BY rating.photo_id 
  ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 10)as alias 
ORDER BY cphoto_id;
```

Comment: it says duplicate user_id as column user_id is same for both table.